# Корректное завершение работы очень многопоточного Java приложения

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть Java приложение с большим количеством потоков(сейчас обычно несколько десятков, в будущем возможно до нескольких сотен и более), исполняемых в течении длительного времени(более 10 минут как минимум).

Каждый поток вносит изменения в назначенную ему строку CSV файла(примитивная база данных). Естественно, работа потоков с файлом синхронизирована.

Приложение может быть в любой момент закрыто пользователем, и необходимо в этот момент менять значение одного параметра(который так же используется во время работы в каждом потоке) в CSV файле, в каждой строке.

Пробовал разобраться сам, просто при закрытии приложения в цикле перебирая все строки и проставляя нужное значение параметра.
В коде это выглядит так(работаю в Netbeans IDE)

```
    private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   



    try {
        DataBase_arr = CSV.GetCSV(fileName);   //Обновили БД в массиве
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    int db_length = DataBase_arr.length - 1;

    int DB_str = 0;
    while (DB_str < db_length) {  

        DataBase_arr[DB_str][9] = "0"; 

        CSV.SaveCSV(DataBase_arr, fileName);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        DB_str++;
    }

 }
```

Но после закрытия приложения всегда остается несколько строк, в которых не внесены нужные изменения. Как я думаю, это происходит из-за того, что некоторые дополнительные потоки завершаются позднее основного, в котором вносятся изменения при закрытии приложения, что является абсолютно нормальным для них поведением.

Но как лучше решить эту проблему, чтобы решение было правильным?

1)При закрытии приложения создавать новый поток, в котором вносить изменения в файл, и надеяться что он завершиться в последнюю очередь? Честно говоря, какое то извращение, и может работать нестабильно, если произойдет ситуация, что запись в файл будет заблокирована другим потоком(на счет этого не уверен).

2)В самом потоке проверять не прерван ли он(ведь при закрытии приложения поток прерывается?), и если прерван, вносить нужные изменения в файл, и только потом выходить из него? Это будет правильно? Как это сделать?

3)Ваши идеи?

P.S. Пожалуйста, не предлагайте использовать пул потоков(вопрос не про это, и он не подходит для решения моих задач.), а так же отказаться от работы с CSV файлом(запланировано в будущем, но пока отказаться от него нет возможности).

Так же не хочется лишний раз трогать приоритеты потоков.

Comment: Правильно будет отслеживать состояние потоков при выходе и ожидать их завершения.

Comment: Судя по коду, ваш csv-файл считывается в память сразу целиком. Вот и читайте его на старте приложения один раз. И работайте с данными в памяти, не обращаясь больше к файлу - это будет быстрее. Зачем-то вы записываете массив в файл столько раз, сколько в нём строк - смысл этого не понятен.